# Array iteration in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to iterate through an array in Ruby. I using `each`method but getting the following error message: ``` NoMethodError: undefined method ``each' for "1, 2":String ```.

I am using `jruby-1.6.7`. Not sure if that is the problem.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

puts "Select one of these.\n1. ABC\n2. DEF\n3. GHI\n"

schemas = gets.chomp

len = schemas.size

puts schemas.split(",")

puts schemas[0..len]

schemas.each {|x| puts x}
```

I need some guidance with iterating through a simple array in Ruby?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not seeing how schemas is an array. If you want to wrap a string to act as an array, then do Array(schemas).each

Comment: You do `schemas.split(",")` but `schemas` not changes. You can do `schemas = schemas.split(",")` then use `schemas.each {}`

Comment: That worked. I did `schemas = schemas.split(",")` and that worked. Thank you for the clear explanation.

Comment: Also `len` has the size of string which should be the size of the array. so `len = schemas.split(",").size` should be what you must have to iterate through the array of the specified length.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track:

```
schemas = gets.chomp
# => "1, 2"

# save the result of split into an array
arr = schemas.split(",")
# => [1, 2]

# loop the array
arr.each { |schema| puts schema }
# => 1
# => 2
```

You can also do this in one line, though the array won't get saved anywhere.

```
schemas = gets.chomp
schemas.split(",").each { |schema| puts schema }
# => 1
# => 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, however you are calling the `Array#each` method on a *String*.

```
schemas = gets.chomp
puts schemas.split(",")
```

It's true that the `String#split` method converts a string to an array, however you never actually converted the data type. `schemas` is still recognized as a string.

What you could do is

```
schemas = schemas.split(",")
```

Then

```
schemas.each{|x| puts x}
```